# imageresizer cannot find ImageResizer.Plugins.IRedactDiagnostics

Tags: imageresizer

I am trying to install and use the RemoteReader plugin, but when I try to execute code, I get the following error:

```
Could not load type ImageResizer.Plugins.IRedactDiagnostics ...
```

This doesn't look like a plugin that gets individually installed/implemented. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like that interface is in the core. Not sure why it's not compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it working. I didn't realize that my core dll was an outdated version.